# Enable TabBar Item in View Controller from Another in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

So I'm new to Xcode and Swift. I'm using the Xcode Beta with Swift 4.

I have two views with a tab bar, and I have the tab bar item on the second view disabled.

I'm wondering if there is anyway that on a button click in the view #1, I can enabled the tab bar item in view #2. Any help is appreciated!

[image: The image]

Comment: probably in your case you just need to use __common__ the tab-tar's navigation-item, and set it enabled or disabled whenever you'd like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep reference of tabBarController in child controllers, and enable/ disable tabbar items using there index like:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0].enabled = false
```